# Trying to automatically register my EC2 instances in Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have approximately 40 Windows EC2 instances running at the moment. This number will start to grow substantially in the next few months.  Each one is a t2.small Windows 2016 Server instance. Cost is starting to become an issue as the number increases.  Each instance has its own Elastic IP address because when user Tom wants to access his machine he will use the DNS `tom.mydomain.com`.

`tom.mydomain.com` is registered in a Route53 hosted zone pointing to Elastic IP `22.33.44.55` which has been associated with Tom's EC2 instance.
Problem is that Tom only needs to use his machine 4 hours per day.  When not using it he simply shuts the machine down. But... An Elastic IP that is pointing to a stopped instance costs almost as much per hour as a t1.micro instance in a running state.

So what I want to do is when Tom logs into AWS console and starts his EC2 instance, it will automatically register itself with Route53 against the DNS "tom.mydomain.com".

In short I want to do away with the need for Elastic IPs which are fast becoming a very substantial cost.

The tutorial [Auto-Register EC2 Instance in AWS Route 53](https://www.esentri.com/auto-register-ec2-instance-in-aws-route-53/)
looks like it does exactly what I want to do. The problem is the scripting is for Linux.  I want to get it working for Windows.  I have everything done down to step 6 in the tutorial but am stuck there. Any one get something similar to this working on Windows?

Comment: Are your users customers or staff members? You probably don't want to be handing AWS credentials to customers. In fact, having them log into the AWS Management Console probably isn't a good idea. You should create a front-end where they can authenticate and activate their instance. This front-end could then manage the DNS allocation when starting the instance.

Comment: An unused Elastic IP address is 0.5c/hour (12c per day). Is that really such a huge concern? Also, have you considered using [Amazon WorkSpaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/amazon-workspaces.html)? It provides a full client experience and has the ability to automatically turn off after inactivity.

Comment: Yes,  looked at Amazon Workspaces.  This option would cost almost twice as much as what I currently have.  Approx $12 pcm per instance ( Idle Elastic IP & running instance cost ) approx 1/3 of cost is for idle Elastic IP.  When I have say 400 idle Elastic IPs that cost will be significant. 0.5c per hr may not seem like much but as number of instances increases so too will the wasted costs of idle Elastic IPs. 400 instances will see us spend $1,400 on idle elastic IPs

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend:

- Create a **web-based front-end** where your users can authenticate and request access to their Amazon EC2 instance

  - You could use **Amazon Cognito** for authentication and **DynamoDB** for data storage
- Once the user authenticates, the service can:

  - **Start** their EC2 instance (if it was previously stopped)
  - Associate the random public IP address to the **customer's domain name**
  - Tell the user that the instance is **now available**
- Users **login** to the instance and perform their work function
- You then have some mechanism (I'm not sure what) that detects that they no longer need the instance, and then **Stops** the instance to save costs

The above process **avoids assigning IAM credentials to your users**. While IAM credentials are important for staff members who work on your AWS infrastructure, they should not be assigned to end-users of your service.

The process also **avoids assigning IAM permissions to each EC2 instance**. While the instances themselves could call Route 53 to update a record for their domain name, this requires an IAM Role to be assigned to the EC2 instance. If your users have access to the instance itself, this would potentially open a security hole where they could call Route 53 with incorrect data, such as assigning other users' domain names to their own instance.

It's worth mentioning that the above recommendations mirror the way that **Amazon WorkSpaces** operates — users authenticate, their instance is started and after a period of non-use the instance is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend use of cloudformation template. Cloudformation can create EC2 and then attach it to route53 url. So when tom like to use the EC2 instance, he have to run the stack in Cloudformation. Once he finished he have to go back to cloudformation and destroy the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Cloudformation would be a recommended approach. You can try [cloudkast](https://krunal4amity.github.io) which is an online cloudformation template generator. It will make your task of creating cloudformation template very easy and effortless